# Is it possible to upload a CSV file of email addresses, and send them all the same email?

Tags: php, email, csv

Basically, I would like to attempt exactly what the title says - I want to upload a CSV of emails, maybe 100 of so values, and run each one through a loop/function for it to be send an email.

I know exactly how to code this, although I would prefer that I ask some experts first before I go ahead with this since I'd like to know if it would be a waste of time or not.

---

So simply, I would have an upload button. This parser would only accept a CSV file, and will check for any errors, simple.

Next I would save the CSV into a large array. I would then grab the first element of the array and save it as a variable. This variable would then be thrown into a function, and run through the email sending process. Once completed, the process will start again with the second value within the array. So on, so on.

- Would something like this be possible?
- Would they be marked as spam?
- Would the best way be with a `function` or a `for each` loop
- Would there be a limit to how large the CSV file could be until something goes wrong?

Comment: yes, it would. Do you have any actual specific questions?

Comment: strongly suggest phpmailer or swiftmailer and NOT using mail()

Comment: questions of the type 'is this possible' usually don't do well here on S.O

Comment: @sevenseacat - Added a few extra questions

Comment: @Dagon - Why do you not suggest `mail()`? Used it plenty of times in the past, and seems quite reliable. Would this change if sending hundreds of emails though..? And what kind of benefits do PHPmailer and swiftmailer have over the simple `mail()` method?

Comment: read what the manual it self says on mail "It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient. "

Comment: @Dagon - It states that it may not be very efficient... But does this just mean that it will be slow? Timewise is not an issue for this task. Don't really mind if I submit a CSV file with 100 emails and it takes 5 minutes or so. Is this what it means exactly?

Comment: these are really vague questions and not at all suited to a Q&A forum like SO. The answer to all of them is 'it depends'.

Comment: both slower, and uses more resources, may or may not be an issue for you, but you should know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would they be marked as spam?

This depends entirely on the content of your emails and where you send them from. Sending them from a reputable IP (typically *not* a residential internet connection), having an SPF record and/or using DKIM, and using proper spelling and not including lots of spam-like URLs will all help. It's also important that if you're using a `From` address of an email provider who DOES use SPF or DKIM that you send using *their* SMTP servers.

In short, it depends, and you have to try it, but as long as you're sending legit email, you shouldn't have too much of a problem.

> Would the best way be with a function or a for each loop

That's up to you and depends on how you structure your code, and without your code it's impossible to make suggestions. Like the others have suggested, I'd recommend using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Not only will this (likely) be more efficient, it will be easier to configure an SMTP server if you need to send through one to get SPF or DKIM.

> Would there be a limit to how large the CSV file could be until
>   something goes wrong?

There's no theoretical limit, but some things to look out for would be the PHP execution time timeout and if your SMTP server (if using one) rate-limits connections or emails.